# Why does my db/structure.sql file contain a CREATE SCHEMA statement after running db:structure:dump?

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5, pg-dump

After migrating my development database, I'm unable to run `rails db:test:prepare`.

My application uses the `db/structure.sql` file to update the test database:

```
# config/application.rb

config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```

When I run `rails db:migrate` (which also runs `db:structure:dump`), my `db/structure.sql` is updated. Unfortunately, it now contains this line near the top after updating:

```
CREATE SCHEMA public;
```

This will bomb when loaded into a database that already contains the `public` schema.

I can manually update that line and the SQL dump loads successfully:

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS public;
```

...but I don't want to do that every time.

I expect the test database to be built successfully from the SQL dump in `db/structure.sql` when I run `rails db:test:prepare` because the SQL dump should not try to create the `public` schema.

Comment: My `structure.sql` doesn't try to create the public schema. Which version of PostgreSQL are you using?

Comment: @muistooshort `psql -V` gives me `psql (PostgreSQL) 11.3`.

Comment: Does it say `CREATE SCHEMA public;` if you manually `pg_dump` your database? I'm wondering if the `pg_dump` output change slightly in PostgreSQL 11 (which I don't have installed).

Comment: @muistooshort I should have stated earlier that I tried migrating databases in versions 9.6 and 11, and it still tries to create the `public` schema in `structure.sql`.

Comment: But which version is *creating* the `db/structure.sql` file?

Comment: @muistooshort From my `db/structure.sql` file:
`-- Dumped from database version 11.3`
`-- Dumped by pg_dump version 11.3`

Comment: A manual `pg_dump` does not include the `CREATE SCHEMA public` line.

Comment: @ulysses_rex I'm running into this problem as well. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @GregW I couldn't find a simple solution. ActiveRecord's postgres adaptor usually calls `pg_dump` with a `--schema=<schema_name>` argument, which creates the line `CREATE SCHEMA <schema_name>`. `pg_dump` gives no option to change this to `...IF EXISTS...`.

Comment: Source: `activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:45`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My development environment config explicitly specified the "public" schema. I removed that specification, which allowed `db:test:prepare` to complete successfully.

```rb
# config/environments/development.rb

Rails.application.configure do
  ...
  config.active_record.dump_schemas = "public" # <<-- DELETED!
end
```

You can configure which database schemas will be dumped when calling `db:structure:dump` by setting [`config.active_record.dump_schemas`](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-active-record) to one of the following options:

- `:schema_search_path`: This looks for the schema names in the `schema_search_path` setting in `config/database.yml`.
- `"<some string>"`: It will dump the schema names in the string. Names here are comma separated values.
- `:all`: No schema names are specified.
- Or just don't set it at all, which is what I did.

If `config.active_record.dump_schemas.blank? == true`, ActiveRecord's Postgres adaptor [will set the `--schema=<schema name>` flag on `pg_dump`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4500ebba21836c4bf264a043b68cf580cfa55611/activerecord/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb#L64-L68), which in turn adds the line `CREATE SCHEMA <schema name>` to its output in `db/structure.sql`.

An interesting side effect is that now `db:test:prepare` inserts this instead:

```sql
CREATE SCHEMA _template;
```